# Cannot read data from underlying reader after wrapping it in BufReader

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, rust

My intention is to access to a `TcpStream` and perform two read operations in two different methods of a struct that holds the `TcpStream` as attribute.

The first operation performs fine but when I try to load the remaining bytes on the second method, the buffer cannot be filled.

I have tried to create a very simple recreation. This is how it works:

1. Some data is sent to a socket (8 bytes)
2. 1 byte is read using `read` and a buffer of 1 byte size. Everything is fine.
3. 1 byte is read using `read_exact` and a buffer of 1 byte size. Everything is fine.
4. 1 byte *should be read* using `read_exact` over the underlying `read` object (`stream` object). The buffer cannot be filled. I get an error if I unwrap, or the buffer with the initial values.

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use std::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream};
    use std::io::{BufReader, Read, Write};

    #[test]
    fn test_read_twice() {
        let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:0").unwrap();
        let local_addr = listener.local_addr().unwrap();
        let mut stream = TcpStream::connect(local_addr).unwrap();
        match listener.accept() {
            Ok((mut socket, _)) => {
                let _ = socket.write_all(&[0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7]);
            }
            Err(e) => println!("couldn't get client: {:?}", e),
        }
        {
            let mut reader = BufReader::new(&mut stream);
            let mut buff = vec![0u8; 1];
            let _ = reader.read(&mut buff[..]).unwrap();
            assert_eq!(buff, vec![0]);
            let mut buff = vec![0u8; 1];
            let _ = reader.read_exact(&mut buff[..]).unwrap();
            assert_eq!(buff, vec![1]);
        }
        let mut buff = vec![88u8; 1];
        let _ = stream.read_exact(&mut buff[..]);
        assert_eq!(buff, vec![2]);
    }
}
```

[gist](https://gist.github.com/blasrodri/0d1e963266feaa7020fca33b38b79379)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point of a [`BufReader`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufReader.html) is to read "ahead" - you only did small reads, but the `BufReader` read a large block from the underlying reader, stored it in a buffer, and serves the `read` requests from that.  This buffer is owned by the `BufReader` - you can't expect to read from that buffer when you call `read` (or `read_exact`) on the underlying reader.

As the `BufReader` interface doesn't expose the internal buffer it usually doesn't make sense to use the underlying reader again later (you can't reliably get to a state where the buffer is empty).  So instead of passing a reference to `BufReader::new` simply pass it by value.  That way you can leave it there forever and still move the `BufReader`/`TcpStream` around if necessary.

You still can access the underlying reader through [`get_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufReader.html#method.get_ref) and [`get_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufReader.html#method.get_mut) if you need to call other (not `Read`-related) functions (or even get it back with [`into_inner`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufReader.html#method.into_inner), but you'll lose buffered data).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This means that in this case, `BufReader` read everything, and thus, there's nothing left to be read, right? I need the feature `read_line` and also to be able to read afterwards from the original `stream`. Any idea?

Comment: @Blas don't unwrap it. Just leave it in the `BufReader` forever.

Comment: @Shepmaster could you give me an example where a BufReader is wrapped in a struct? In that case, I could use it across several methods. I don't mind creating a new question, if that would be the proper way here.

Comment: @Blas not sure what you mean with "wrapped in a struct", but maybe my updated answer contains what you're looking for.

Comment: That was the best answer. I never realized that I could pass it by value. Thanks a lot, @Stefan